# cdf player poiseuille flow

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, fluid-dynamics

i am trying to model the dynamic behavior of a micropolar fluid. From the equations of motion we derive the analytical solution for the fluid velocity which is [image]

I am interested only in u(y). I found an online code posted by William C. Guttner which i have slightly modified as follows:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{Ux, plt, n, h, nr, ca, cd},
  n = 1;
  h = 0.1;
  Ux[y_] := 
   1 - (y/h)^2 - ((2*nr)/(n + nr))*1/
     Sqrt[( (4*n)/(ca + cd))*(nr/(n + nr))*h^2]*((
      Cosh[Sqrt[( (4*n)/(ca + cd))*(nr/(n + nr))*h^2]] - 
       Cosh[(Sqrt[( (4*n)/(ca + cd))*(nr/(n + nr))*h^2])*y/h])/
      Sinh[Sqrt[( (4*n)/(ca + cd))*(nr/(n + nr))*h^2]]);





plt = ListPlot[Table[{Ux[y], y}, {y, -h, h, 0.001}], 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2.2}, {-h - 0.02, h + 0.02}}, Joined -> True,
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[.25, .43, .82]}, 
    ImageSize -> {500, 400}, AxesLabel -> {x, y} ]; 
  Show[plt, 
   Graphics[
    Table[{RGBColor[.25, .43, .82], Arrowheads[Medium], 
      Arrow[{{0, 2*h/12*y - h}, {Ux[2*h/12*y - h], 
         2*h/12*y - h}}]}, {y, 0, 12}]], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
     Text[Style[
       Row[{Style["u", Italic], " = ", 
         Subscript[Style["U", Italic], 0]}], RGBColor[.25, .43, .82], 
       Bold, 18], {1.8, h + 0.015}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
     Text[Style[Row[{Style["u", Italic], " = 0"}], 
       RGBColor[.25, .43, .82], Bold, 18], {1.8, -h - 0.015}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
     Line[{{-0.5, -.1}, {2.2, -.1}}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
     Line[{{-0.5, .1}, {2.2, .1}}]}],
   Graphics[ {Thickness[0.001], 
     RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], {Blue, 
      Arrow[{{2, h + 0.015}, {2.2, h + 0.015}}]}}]]
  ],
 {{nr, -0.1, Row[{"first parameter ", Text@Style["nr", Italic]}]}, 1, 
  10, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ca, -0.1, Row[{"second parameter ", Text@Style["ca", Italic]}]}, 1,
   10, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{cd, -0.1, Row[{"third parameter ", Text@Style["cd", Italic]}]}, 1, 
  10, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

The problem is that i am new to mathematica but also that i am getting many errors when i run this. 
Please any help is much appreciated.
in the next link is the sample code i have found. The problem is related to the couette flow. link --> http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CouetteFlow/

Also, the code before the changes i ve made, was the following,

```
 Manipulate[
 Module[{Ux, plt, μ, h},
  μ = 1*10^-3;
  h = 0.1;
  Ux[y_] := Uo/2 (1 + y/h) + ((-c) h^2)/(2 μ) (1 - (y/h)^2);
  plt = ListPlot[Table[{Ux[y], y}, {y, -h, h, 0.001}], 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2.2}, {-h - 0.02, h + 0.02}}, Joined -> True,
     PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[.25, .43, .82]}, 
    ImageSize -> {500, 400}, AxesLabel -> {x, y} ]; 
  Show[plt, 
   Graphics[
    Table[{RGBColor[.25, .43, .82], Arrowheads[Medium], 
      Arrow[{{0, 2*h/12*y - h}, {Ux[2*h/12*y - h], 
         2*h/12*y - h}}]}, {y, 0, 12}]], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
     Text[Style[
       Row[{Style["u", Italic], " = ", 
         Subscript[Style["U", Italic], 0]}], RGBColor[.25, .43, .82], 
       Bold, 18], {1.8, h + 0.015}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0, 0, 1], 
     Text[Style[Row[{Style["u", Italic], " = 0"}], 
       RGBColor[.25, .43, .82], Bold, 18], {1.8, -h - 0.015}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
     Line[{{-0.5, -.1}, {2.2, -.1}}]}], 
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.025], RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
     Line[{{-0.5, .1}, {2.2, .1}}]}],
   Graphics[ {Thickness[0.001], 
     RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], {Blue, 
      Arrow[{{2, h + 0.015}, {2.2, h + 0.015}}]}}]]
  ],
 {{Uo, 0.5, 
   Row[{"upper plate velocity ", 
     Text@Subscript[Style["U", Italic], 0]}]}, 0, 1, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c, -0.1, 
   Row[{"pressure gradient ", 
     Text@Style["d\[InvisibleSpace]p"/"d\[InvisibleSpace]x", 
       Italic]}]}, 0.1, -0.3, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Copy-pasteable code please, not images :)

Comment: Also, please provide a link to the author of the code.

Comment: sorry about that. I had never posted here in the past .